# How To calculate discount in Crinsane/laravel

Tags: laravel-5, discount

I want to ask about how to calculate discount in laravel using Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart, i try to search a lot to understand ho to add the discount but i failed, i hope someone help me soon.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far with code?

Comment: Ok thanks i solve it by calculate discount in card controller